# Functions in Structures ? C++

Tags: c++, structure

I understand how a basic `struct` works in C++, as in this example:

```
struct Options 
{
   int num_particles;
   bool use_lbp;
   string infile;
   string outfile;
};
```

However, I do not understand the following, where in the declaration there is an additional section. What is the purpose of `Options():...`?

```
struct Options 
{
   Options()
      :num_particles(NUM_PARTICLES),
       use_lbp(false),
       infile(),
       outfile()
   {}

   int num_particles;
   bool use_lbp;
   string infile;
   string outfile;
};
```

Is this similar to what is going on in the code below?

```
struct State_
{
   State_( State pp ) : p( pp ) { }
   operator State() { return p; }
   State p;
};
```

Comment: A [good introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) will tell you about constructors, and other basic language features.

Comment: It's a member function, just like in a class.

Comment: Do you know what those do for classes?

Comment: The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C++ is the default visibility of members, in a `struct` it's `public` while in a `class` it's `private`.

Comment: In all honesty, I am familiar with both classes and structures but that `Options:` construction is not something I've seen before. It looks like a constructor which calls a number of other functions – except they are struct members?

Comment: @Jongware: You've not seen an [initialiser list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) before? That's how the constructor specifies how each base class and member is initialised.

Comment: @Mike: nope :) Coming from C, I tend to treat classes as "structs with functions". Never crossed my mind that structs themselves gained something as well. (Good link though. Mental note: have to read.)

Comment: I think the most important point is that there is no other way to initialize a struct or class that has a reference or a const qualified member but using the initialiser list

Comment: @DarthB well these days you can also initialize them with a brace-or-equal initializer, but that's just a new syntax for the same thing.

Comment: @DarthB If the struct were an aggregate (i.e. if the constructor were removed), it could also be initialized with an initialization list.

Comment: Ahh you mean my_struct = {a_ref, a_val1, ..., a_val2}; will also work!? Did not think about that, good point.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this is not the only difference. With classes inheritance is private by default (public with structs)

Comment: @Haziq: I reworded the question to remove the asking for "website that I can visit, videos I can watch (etc.), which was (I think) the primary reason for closure. I made the question focus on *this single construction* instead, so it's a better fit for Stack Overflow's Q&A model. (You may want to read the [tour] some time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Options()` is your default constructor. Structs and classes are equivalent in the sense that they can have methods and constructors. What's after `:` is the initialisation list for `Options()`. It tells you that in your default constructor for `Options()`:

- `num_particles` is initialised to `NUM_PARTICLES`
- `ule_lbp` is initialised to `false`
- `infile` initialised to an empty string
- `outfile` initialised to an empty string

Similar line of reasoning applies for `State_`.